# Creating "Local" Z Depth

Tags: eevee-render-engine, mathematics, vector, depth-map

For context, I'm trying to create a stylized shader in Eevee that will allow for me to create a "halo" effect around the outline of carded hair, similar to that of fresnel/facing. However, with such a dense and jagged mesh, it seems impossible to achieve such a smooth effect using a normal-based approach.

[image: Z Depth vs Facing]

After a bit of fiddling, I found that z-depth achieves my desired result, but that creates a whole host of problems on its own! Panning or zooming in and out will ruin the effect.

[image: Me Zooming]

With all that said, is there some mathematical solution that only considers the z depth within the space of a given object (white in front and black in the back)? And if z depth isn't doable, is there any other Blender feature that can achieve it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend making a special "thickness" map for you hair.  For me, making hair textures from particle renders, I'll do a map of particle volume emission to get this thickness map.  Where the strands are thin, at their edges, you'll have translucency; at their centers, or where they are layered up, they won't.

With a map like that, you can mix diffuse (or whatever) with translucency, which is just diffuse from backwards normals.  You will generally want to top this out at a 0.5/0.5 mix max translucency.

Because the hair cards will be shadowed by the head and by other hair cards, translucency will be black for the sections of hair you're showing as darker.  Only where they are on the edge of the mesh, unshadowed, will you get translucency.  This does require adjusting your diffuse to compensate.

That said, I do have a few comments on other stuff you said.  I don't think z-depth is what you want, and I think it's entirely an artifact of your particular view (and mesh) that it does what you want here.  It is simply the distance from the camera to the mesh, which is not the same thing as the outline of the hair.  However, sometimes there are situations where stuff looks good at one depth, but not at another-- like bump maps being too strong when close and too weak when far-- and you can do things like use a camera info node to mix between multiple sets of parameters at different depths.  (Most stuff that depends on depth also depends on FOV, but that's harder to correct for, requiring drivers and a lot of math, so it's generally easier to just ignore the FOV aspect of it and tune for a relatively stable FOV.)

The closest thing you're going to get to the depth of the object, scaled to the bounds of the object, centered on the bounding box of the object, is this:

[image]

But, again, I don't think this is going to do what you want it to do.  The edge of a mesh is not at any consistent depth to the camera.  Think about physics blowing the edges of your hair back and forth, closer and further from the camera: the depth of the silhouette will be changing constantly.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, and yeah that might be the best way to go, but I've seen a technique very similar to what I mentioned used before (not in Blender though) with really good results. At this point I'd just like to see if it's possible.

The heart of my question was as you said: things will change depending on how far the camera is (though I didn't consider FOV!) so I wonder what can be done to counteract it, if any. I tried fiddling with the camera data node but got nowhere, probably because I don't know what I need to do in the first place.

Comment: I really appreciate the thought you put into this, even if you knew if it wasn't necessarily the best approach. I guess that's something I must learn the hard way as I continue playing with this.

Comment: Yeah, I know, sometimes you just have to do what you think might work, even when other people tell you it won't.  I have done that plenty of times myself.  And there isn't really anything wrong with trying: you always end up learning stuff as you go.

Answer (score 2):

If Z-depth style works for you ... you can use *Empty* in a center of object as *Texture Coordinator* to keep it independent on Camera distance, but it will generates the same silhouethe issues as in z-depth.

*Empty* with **Damped Track** *Constraint* to *Camera*.

[image]

[image]

It is not clear to me how halo should work ... if you want to use backlight why don't use Transluent shader or SSS directly?

Comment: Thank you so much! Both you and Nathan pretty much answered my question, so picking one is difficult. I actually did try using translucency, and it didn't give me the results I wanted. (Though as Nathan mentioned, that's probably because I need to use a thickness map. I'll save any problems I run into for another ask.)